# How to observe node.current.clientHeight has changed in React?

Tags: reactjs, use-ref

I try to observe wether a div height has changed:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const h = node.current.clientHeight;
  setHeight(h);
}, [node.current]);
```

```
<div
  style={{
    position: "absolute",
  }}
  ref={node}
>
```

The problem that the height of the div become bigger and useEffect will not be notified about it.

I tried to use `setTimeout` with 5 sec, but user experience is really bed. What would you suggest?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React: How to observe node.current.clientHeight has changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69498757/react-how-to-observe-node-current-clientheight-has-changed)

Comment: (You have _28krep_, you should have a better idea of the basics of using this site.)

Comment: @jonrsharpe, would you tell me what is the major problem with my questions? grammar?

Comment: Grammar is easy enough to fix with an edit (e.g. wether -> whether, bed -> bad). In this case that you reposted instead of editing and improving the existing one. In fact it's not even _as good_ as the previous one, this lacks any context (risking an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248731)).

Comment: Because they complained about the "minimal reproducible example", but sorry to say, I do not have time, and maybe the ability do make in that HTML editor. But usually I fix my grammar issues I am aware of. I didn't thought "whether" is with two "h". :D

Comment: If you don't have the time to meet the requirements of [ask], it's unreasonable to expect others to take the time to answer. And this _isn't_ a [mre].

Comment: I do my best. Fortunatelly I got many help here.

Answer (score 0):

No need for filtering of the `useEffect`'s event:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (node && node.current && node.current.clientHeight) {
    setHeight(node.current.clientHeight);
  }
});
```